# loop through textboxes c#

Tags: c#, sql, properties

I have 5 text-boxes and I want to loop over them and get each text-box value and insert it into a table on a separate row. How can I do that? I tried something like this:

```
TextBox[] rasp = new TextBox[] { textbox1, textBox2, textBox3, 
                                 textBox4, textBox5 };

foreach (TextBox  raspuns in rasp) {
     SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(
  ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["chestionar"].ConnectionString);
     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
        "INSERT INTO Raspunsuri Values('" + raspuns +"',@cnp,@data,'5')", con);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cnp", Session["sesiune_cnp"]);
     //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@raspuns", raspuns);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data", DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime());
}
```

Comment: You should move the SQLConnection code outside the loop

Comment: You can go with George's solution but can I suggest that you move the SqlConnection code outside the loop.

Comment: i like how the two values you control are parameterized, and the value vulnerable to injection is thrown right in the query

Comment: and what to put in the foreach?

Answer (score 2):

You probably meant:

```
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Raspunsuri Values('" + raspuns.Text +"',@cnp,@data,'5')", con);
```

instead of:

```
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Raspunsuri Values('" + raspuns +"',@cnp,@data,'5')", con);
```

As you cannot concatenate `string` and `TextBox` as it is an object whose one of fields is `Text` which contains the text entered into it.

Note: Beware of SQL injection attacks, don't do this this way, instead resort back to your commented out solution with `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@raspuns", raspuns.Text);`. Again, make sure to put `raspuns.Text`.

Comment: Ah, yes I missed the other reference to `raspuns` good catch.

Comment: I only get the value of the first textbox..Can you give a solution?

Comment: @user1147188 What do you mean by "I only get the value of the first textbox"? Is the only first one stored? Or you get empty string for others? Or you get some error? Please be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the problem is an error with this line:

```
//cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@raspuns", raspuns);
```

Change it to:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@raspuns", raspuns.Text);
```